# what is the best config for xmr-stak to mine monero?

Tags: configuration, config, cryptocurrency, mining

My tech spec is dual intel gold 6140 (36 cores 2.3ghz) 96gb ram, 2 800gb ssd (raid) and 2 nvidia v100 32gb cards. (i don;t have access to bios to overclock)

I was wondering what would be the best config and setup to get the most hashes? currently I'm getting 3000-4000 h/s thats both gpu and cpu combined. I allowed the large pages and increase page size to 64gb (not sure if that was necessery or not) also I installed latest cuda.

this is my cpu config not sure if i'm getting the max amount of threads out of it, also i get some error that it can't go to 86 only 63, not sure what it means.

```
"cpu_threads_conf" :
[
    { "low_power_mode" : false, "no_prefetch" : true, "asm" : "auto", "affine_to_cpu" : 0 },
    { "low_power_mode" : false, "no_prefetch" : true, "asm" : "auto", "affine_to_cpu" : 2 },
    { "low_power_mode" : false, "no_prefetch" : true, "asm" : "auto", "affine_to_cpu" : 4 },
    { "low_power_mode" : false, "no_prefetch" : true, "asm" : "auto", "affine_to_cpu" : 6 },
    { "low_power_mode" : false, "no_prefetch" : true, "asm" : "auto", "affine_to_cpu" : 8 },
    { "low_power_mode" : false, "no_prefetch" : true, "asm" : "auto", "affine_to_cpu" : 10 },
    { "low_power_mode" : false, "no_prefetch" : true, "asm" : "auto", "affine_to_cpu" : 12 },
    { "low_power_mode" : false, "no_prefetch" : true, "asm" : "auto", "affine_to_cpu" : 14 },
    { "low_power_mode" : false, "no_prefetch" : true, "asm" : "auto", "affine_to_cpu" : 16 },
    { "low_power_mode" : false, "no_prefetch" : true, "asm" : "auto", "affine_to_cpu" : 18 },
    { "low_power_mode" : false, "no_prefetch" : true, "asm" : "auto", "affine_to_cpu" : 20 },
    { "low_power_mode" : false, "no_prefetch" : true, "asm" : "auto", "affine_to_cpu" : 22 },
    { "low_power_mode" : false, "no_prefetch" : true, "asm" : "auto", "affine_to_cpu" : 24 },
    { "low_power_mode" : false, "no_prefetch" : true, "asm" : "auto", "affine_to_cpu" : 26 },
    { "low_power_mode" : false, "no_prefetch" : true, "asm" : "auto", "affine_to_cpu" : 28 },
    { "low_power_mode" : false, "no_prefetch" : true, "asm" : "auto", "affine_to_cpu" : 30 },
    { "low_power_mode" : false, "no_prefetch" : true, "asm" : "auto", "affine_to_cpu" : 64 },
    { "low_power_mode" : false, "no_prefetch" : true, "asm" : "auto", "affine_to_cpu" : 66 },
    { "low_power_mode" : false, "no_prefetch" : true, "asm" : "auto", "affine_to_cpu" : 68 },
    { "low_power_mode" : false, "no_prefetch" : true, "asm" : "auto", "affine_to_cpu" : 70 },
    { "low_power_mode" : false, "no_prefetch" : true, "asm" : "auto", "affine_to_cpu" : 72 },
    { "low_power_mode" : false, "no_prefetch" : true, "asm" : "auto", "affine_to_cpu" : 74 },
    { "low_power_mode" : false, "no_prefetch" : true, "asm" : "auto", "affine_to_cpu" : 76 },
    { "low_power_mode" : false, "no_prefetch" : true, "asm" : "auto", "affine_to_cpu" : 78 },
    { "low_power_mode" : false, "no_prefetch" : true, "asm" : "auto", "affine_to_cpu" : 80 },
    { "low_power_mode" : false, "no_prefetch" : true, "asm" : "auto", "affine_to_cpu" : 82 },
    { "low_power_mode" : false, "no_prefetch" : true, "asm" : "auto", "affine_to_cpu" : 84 },
    { "low_power_mode" : false, "no_prefetch" : true, "asm" : "auto", "affine_to_cpu" : 86 },

],
```

this is my gpu config (default)

```
"gpu_threads_conf" :
[
  // gpu: Tesla V100-PCIE-32GB architecture: 70
  //      memory: 32127/32642 MiB
  //      smx: 80
  { "index" : 0,
    "threads" : 4, "blocks" : 640,
    "bfactor" : 6, "bsleep" :  25,
    "affine_to_cpu" : true, "sync_mode" : 1,
    "mem_mode" : 1,
  },
  // gpu: Tesla V100-PCIE-32GB architecture: 70
  //      memory: 32127/32642 MiB
  //      smx: 80
  { "index" : 1,
    "threads" : 4, "blocks" : 640,
    "bfactor" : 6, "bsleep" :  25,
    "affine_to_cpu" : true, "sync_mode" : 1,
    "mem_mode" : 1,
  },

],
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct option would be to test out how much mining your rig gets done when slightly changing your specs then try to compare it to the energy cost/ damage your CPUs and GPUs are accumulating and decide what is the best settings based on that.  I believe using even numbered values will most likely give best results and making sure each thread has at least enough cache memory for holding a hash seems intuitive. Also check to make sure your cards do not require a dummy video output or video output short in-order to run at max capacity. Some miners i've see need hacked video shorts for max performance. [image: dummy plug]